# BuildFire: Plugin marketplace review timeline

Tags: buildfire

I have submitted my plugin to the marketplace for review but it's been over 10 business days; still says pending. I am trying to understand the process as we have many plugins to submit to the marketplace.

I have completed the required steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A human at BuildFire has to review and manually approve the plugin. It's possible they haven't had the chance to review it just yet, or the review is just taking longer for whatever reason. It might be worth while to follow-up with BuildFire customer service, and gently nudge them.